# Javascript call class method in other function

Tags: javascript

I was trying to call a function inside a class function.
Like the following code. I want to call `addMarks` in my `init()` function.
But it threw this error

> $.get(...).bind is not a function

```
class MapManager {
  init(){
    $('#search').click(function(event) {
      if(start && destination){
        $.get('routes/search', {data: 123}, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
          this.addMarks(data.data);
        }).bind(this);
      }
    });
  }

  addMarks(locations){
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: In click and get request callbacks use arrow function

Comment: You can only call `.bind` on another function. `$.get` returns a jqXHR object. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: Have a look at [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're binding `this` to `$.get` there, instead of the `successFn`.

Or else, you can always assign `this` beforehand and access it inside the `successFn` scope.

E.g.

```
class MapManager {
  init(){
    let self = this; // <-- assign it here

    $('#search').click(function(event) {
      if(start && destination){
        $.get('routes/search', {data: 123}, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
          // Yes! I can access 'self' here because it is defined where I am defined.
          self.addMarks(data.data);
        });
      }
    });
  }

  addMarks(locations){
    console.log(":: addMarks");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since you're using `class` so therefore modern javascript, you can forget bind altogether, using arrow function notation

```
class MapManager {
  init(){
    $('#search').click((event) => {
      if(start && destination){
        $.get('routes/search', {data: 123}, (data, textStatus, xhr) => {
          this.addMarks(data.data);
        });
      }
    });
  }

  addMarks(locations){
    ...
  }
}
```